# Converting an ISO 8601 string to Current TimeZone DateTime Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone, momentjs

I am writing a NodeJS app that sends notification based on recently uploaded youtube videos.

I get this ISO 8601 format string from 2015-06-10T20:18:45.000Z from youtube. That string is the time of a video upload.

How can I take that string, convert it to a Date object of my local time zone, get it's time. Then see how long ago from right now was the video exactly uploaded?

I basically need to know exactly how long ago from right now was the video uploaded. If there is a different way than the once I described above that's fine as well.

I tried this but it doesn't work - because of the Time Zone difference I believe

```
var temp_one = new Date('2015-06-10T20:18:45.000Z');
var temp_two = new Date();
var difference = temp_two - temp_one
```

Answer (score 0):

What you described will indeed work - as long as the browser supports parsing the ISO8601 formatted string that you are providing.  Older browsers (such as IE8) don't support this directly.

The `difference` variable will return the number of milliseconds elapsed since the date you provided.  If you want it in some other units, you can divide the number accordingly:

```
var seconds = difference / 1000;
var minutes = difference / 60000;
var hours = difference / 3600000;
```

If you want something more elaborate, you can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

For example:

```
moment("2015-06-10T20:18:45.000Z").fromNow()  // "7 hours ago"
```

Comment: Hey, what I mentioned does convert it but it converts it wrong. How can I get a numerical value from moment?

Comment: What do you mean "converts it wrong".  Please show what you are getting vs what you expect.  And what do you mean by "a numerical value" - if you mean milliseconds since the Unix epoch - then use `.valueOf()`.  (it's [in the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-offset/))